# How do I get the value of an entry and enter it in Ssol.txt?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pygame

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

win = Tk()
win.title("hello")
win.geometry('510x50+200+100')
Block = IntVar()

def x():
    k = open("Ssol.txt", 'w')

Entry(win, width=5, textvariable=Block).grid(column=1, row=0,sticky=(N,W,E))
ttk.Button(win, text="실행", command=x).grid(column=0, row=1,sticky=(W,E))

mainloop()
```

I want to get the value of entry and input it in Ssol.txt.

```
def x():
    k = open("write_Value.txt", 'w')
```

I can understand this but I do not understand when I search for input in Google
so then I want to know how to get the Entry value and enter it in Ssol.txt.
:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `.get()` to access the value of your `IntVar`:

```
from tkinter import *

win = Tk()
Block = IntVar()

def Block_to_file():
    contents = str(Block.get())
    with open("Ssol.txt", 'w') as f:
        f.write(contents)

Entry(win, width=15, textvariable=Block).grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E))
Button(win, text='Write to file', command=Block_to_file).grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=(W, E))

mainloop()
```